# Solve the differential equation $L^2 y=0$ where $L=x^2\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+x\frac{d}{dx}-(x^2+1)\text{id}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions

Consider the linear differential equation defined by
$$
L^2y=0,\quad \text{where}\ L:=x^2\frac{d}{dx^2}+x\frac{d}{dx}-(x^2+1)\text{id}. \tag{1}$$
Here $\text{id}$ denotes the identity operator, and $L^2$ denotes the operator $L$ applied twice. Written out explicitly, (1) is of the form
$$x^4\frac{d^4 y}{dx^4}+6 x^3\frac{d^3y}{dx^3}+(5x^2-2x^4)\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-(x+6x^3)\frac{dy}{dx}+(x^2-1)^2y=0. \tag{2}$$
I am interested in the general solution to (1) which is bounded at $x=0$.

Since the solution that we are looking for is bounded at $x=0$, we may write it as
$$y(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n,$$
near the origin. Substituting the above solution into (2) and equating the coefficient of $x^n$ to be zero, we obtain the following recurrence relation
$$ a_2=\frac{2}{9}a_0,\quad a_3=\frac{1}{8}a_1,\quad a_4=\frac{1}{75}a_0,\quad a_5=\frac{1}{192}{a_1},\quad a_6=\frac{4}{11025}a_0,\quad\dots.$$
Setting $(a_0,a_1)=(1,0)$ and $(a_0,a_1)=(0,1)$, we obtain two linearly independent solutions whose linear combination gives the general solution to (1) bounded at $x=0$.

The solution to with $(a_0,a_1)=(0,1)$ can be written as
$$
y_1(x)=x+\frac{1}{8}x^3+\frac{1}{192}x^5+\cdots=2I_1(x),$$
where $I_1(x)$ is the modified Bessel function of the first kind, while the solution with $(a_0,a_1)=(1,0)$ can be represented as
$$
y_2(x)=1+\frac{2}{9}x^2+\frac{1}{75}x^4+\frac{4}{11025}x^6+\cdots$$
My question is that: can $y_2(x)$ be represented in terms of any special function (like $y_1(x))$?

**Update:** As pointed out in the comments, the $x^0$ coefficient relation gives $a_0=0$, so the solution $y_2(x)$ doest not exist.

Comment: $$L^2y(x)={x}^{4}{\frac {{\rm d}^{4}}{{\rm d}{x}^{4}}}y \left( x \right) -2\,{x}
^{4}{\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{x}^{2}}}y \left( x \right) +{x}^{4}y
 \left( x \right) +6\,{x}^{3}{\frac {{\rm d}^{3}}{{\rm d}{x}^{3}}}y
 \left( x \right) -6\,{x}^{3}{\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}x}}y \left( x
 \right) +5\,{x}^{2}{\frac {{\rm d}^{2}}{{\rm d}{x}^{2}}}y \left( x
 \right) -2\,{x}^{2}y \left( x \right) -x{\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}x}}y
 \left( x \right) +y \left( x \right) $$

Comment: I'm quite sure that the degree 0 coefficient relation gives $a_0=0$.

Comment: @Leox Thanks. I have edited the question to include your comment.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Yes, you are right. I ignored the constant term $a_0$ which should also be set to be  $0$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann This means that there is only one linearly independent solution bounded at zero? I expect that the number of linearly dependent solutions bounded at zero will be two.

Comment: Yes. You have a regular singularity at $x=0$. The other basis solution starts with $x^{-1}$ and possibly contains logarithm terms, so it is unbounded at zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per a c.a.s. the general solution is
\begin{split}y(x) = A I_1(x) + B K_1(x) + C \left[-I_1(x) \int_{x_0}^x \frac{K_1(t)^2 \,dt}{t} + K_1(x) \int_{x_0}^x \frac{I_1(x) K_1(x)}{x}\,dt \right] \qquad \qquad \\+ D \left[\frac{1}{2} K_1(x) \left(I_0(x)^2 - I_1(x)^2\right) - I_1(x) \int_{x_0}^x \frac{I_1(x) K_1(x)}{x}\,dt\right] ,\end{split} where $I_\alpha, K_\alpha$ are the modified Bessel functions of the First and Second Kinds, respectively.

Expanding in a series shows that as $x \searrow 0$,
$$y(x) = \frac{1}{2} C \frac{\log x}{x} + o\left(\frac{\log x}{x}\right),$$
so for any solution bounded near $x = 0$ we must have $C = 0$. Expanding $y(x) \vert_{C = 0}$ around $x = 0$ now gives
$$y(x) = \left(B + \frac{D}{2}\right) \frac{1}{x} + o\left(\frac{1}{x}\right),$$
so boundedness near $0$ implies that $D = -2 B ,$ and expanding $y(x) \vert_{C = 0, D = -2B}$ gives a $2$-parameter family of solutions bounded near $0$; n.b. all of these functions are odd. Now the series expansion as $x \searrow 0$ is
$$\frac{B}{2} x \log x + \left(\frac{A}{2} - \frac{B}{4}\right) x + o(x) ,$$ so the solutions are bounded exactly for such choices of coefficient. Rewriting per the below comment of Maxim gives a simple expression for the general bounded solution:
$$y(x) = a I_1(x) + b \left(\frac{I_0(x)}{x} - K_1(x)\right) .$$

Comment: Thanks. I have a question. How do you obtain the general solution in terms of Bessel functions? Is there any reference?

Comment: Do you mean, how did I solve for $y(x)$ in the first place? If so, I used Maple, a c.a.s.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: To approach this o.d.e. manually, you can use the fact that since $L$ is linear, any solution of $L y = 0$---in particular the Bessel functions $I_1, K_1$---satisfies the given equation, $L^2 y = L(L y) = L(0) = 0$, so you can apply the method of reduction of order to replace $L^2 y = 0$ with an o.d.e. of lower order.

Comment: @XiangYu The coefficient $(A - B)/2$ at $x^3$ should be $(A - B)/16$ and $-I_1(x) + \int_{x_0}^x$ should be $-I_1(x) \int_{x_0}^x$. The Frobenius method generalizes to higher order ODEs. Solving the recurrence relation for the coefficients gives
$$c_{2 k} =
\frac {k + 1} {4^k \left( \left(
 \frac {3 + a} 2 \right)_{\! k} \, \right)^2}.$$
The family of solutions bounded near the origin is
$$\frac {2 A - B} 2 I_1(x) +
 \frac B 2 \sum_{k \geq 0} \left.
  \frac \partial {\partial a} c_{2 k} x^{2 k + a}
  \right|_{a = 1} =
C_1 I_1(x) + C_2 \left( \frac {I_0(x)} x - K_1(x) \right).$$